# Refering to an associating-name in another associating entity in the same ASSOCIATE construct

Tags: fortran

I appologize if my standardese isn't very good but Isn't the following legal Fortran 2008?

```
program test
  implicit none

  associate ( a => 6, b => 2*a )
    print*, b
  end associate

end program
```

My compiler complains about `a` not being declared and not having an implicit type.

**Edit:**

I think the selector can only be an expression or variable and never be an associate-name or an expression involving one. Is this the case?

Comment: In short you use `implicit none` so no variables are defined.

Comment: Well, ``a`` is an associate-name, so it's not really a variable. Same for ``b``.  The thing is, is the second assoc-entity allowed?

Comment: I think that the standard says that names defined in the `associate` statement are in scope inside the block which lies between the statement and the `end associate` statement.  The second use of `a` in the `associate` statement is not inside the block.  I wonder (no Fortran compiler on this machine) if one could nest the `associate` constructs to achieve OP's objective ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (nested) version that does what you wish, and your version which does not comply with the Fortran standard,

```
program test
implicit none
integer a ! note that a has be defined here because it is used as a VARIABLE in the association list below
associate ( a => 6, b => 2*a )
    print*, b
end associate
associate ( a => 6 )
    associate ( b => 2*a )
        print*, b
    end associate
end associate
end program
```

Here is the output of the program compiled by Gfortran,

```
$gfortran -std=gnu main.f90 -o main
$main
   483386368
          12
```

According to the Fortran standard, the `associate` construct allows one to associate a name either with a variable or with the value of an expression, **for the duration of a block**. Here is the general syntax,

```
[ construct-name: ] associate ( association-list )
    block
end associate [ construct-name ]
```

Therefore, I believe your usage of the `associate` construct does not comply with the standard. Basically, in your code, the compiler assumes that `a` in `b => 2*a` in the association list refers to a variable `a` that has been already defined outside the associate construct and list (as opposed to the name `a` that is defned in the association list).

As @HighPerformanceMark suggested, nested `associate` constructs like the example above could achieve your desired goal.